# Using regional language in php/html

Tags: php, html

I am working on a php based site where some texts are greek and some are english. Greek texts are not showing correctly. The file is saved in UTF-8. Is there anything special to do in the header of the html page to show the greek text correctly? My header is like -

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Also when I submit a form containing greek text, I am using -

```
$firstname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['firstname']);
```

Is this okay to use "mysql_real_escape_string" here?

Comment: do you have problems with database data only or, all texts on the page?

Comment: Can you post an url to the page?

Comment: I found the problem. it is in database. Now i am using only $_POST['data'] and inserting it to the database and it is inserting garbage. but when i print the query and run it in the phpmyadmin, then it is okay. i cannot sort out the problem. in the database, the i am using collation as "utf8_general_ci".

Comment: INSERT INTO `usersprofiles` ( `usersp_id` , `usersp_firstname` , `usersp_lastname` , `usersp_address` , `usersp_number` , `usersp_postalcode` , `usersp_city` , `usersp_landline` , `usersp_cellphone` , `usersp_email` , `usersp_foundItOutFrom` , `usersp_category` , `usersp_comments` , `usersp_wherehewent` ) VALUES ( '106' , 'κατωτέρω', 'Παρακαλούμε', 'καμία', NULL , 'καμία', 'καμία', '', 'καμία', 'asd@asd.com', NULL , NULL , NULL , NULL )--------------this is my sql

Comment: Garbage in database is normal if you use UTF-8 collation for non-ansi text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

- Set the collation of your database/ tables/ rows to UTF-8. `UTF8_general_ci` should do.
- Set the connection between MySQL and PHP to UTF-8. (By executing the query `SET NAMES 'utf8'` after connecting or by setting the default connection encoding).
- Try sending the content-type header with PHP: `header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");`.

Comment: mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'")---worked for me. Thanks a lot